# Explaining GRU equations from two sources

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, rnn

I really confused about how GRU computation really works. I am not really good at math btw.

I read the original source of GRU equations from Cho, et al. (2014), and also a Colah's blog post on the same topic.

And somehow, GRU equations at Colah's blog post [Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) are different than equations in the Cho's original paper [Learning Phrase Representations using RNN Encoder–Decoder for Statistical Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1078v3.pdf).

These are the equations from Colah's blog:

$$z_t = \sigma(W_z \cdot [h_{t-1},x_t])$$

$$r_t = \sigma(W_r \cdot [h_{t-1},x_t])$$

$$h_t = (1-z_t) \ast h_{t-1} + z_t \ast \tilde{h}_t$$

$$\tilde h_t = tanh(W \cdot [r_t \ast h_{t-1}, x_t]_j)$$

These are the equations from the original paper:

$$z_j = \sigma([\mathbf W_z \mathbf x]_j + [\mathbf U_z \mathbf h_{(t-1)}]_j)$$

$$r_j = \sigma([\mathbf W_r \mathbf x]_j + [\mathbf U_r \mathbf h_{(t-1)}]_j)$$

$$h_j^{(t)} = z_jh_j^{(t-1)} + (1-z_j) \tilde h_j^{(t)}$$

$$\tilde h_j^{(t)} = \phi([\mathbf W \mathbf x]_j + [\mathbf U(\mathbf r \odot h_{(t-1)})]_j)$$

Can someone explain if Colah's equations are the same as the equations in the paper version?

Answer (score 2):

The equations are ***almost*** the same. First of all, they are written in a slightly different form. In Cho, et al. (2014), it is written that $W_r$ and $U_r$ are weight matrices which are learned. While in Colah's blog, both matrices are referred to as $W$.

For example you could write these two equivalent forms:

$z_j = \sigma([W_z x]_j + [W_z h_{t-1}]_j)$

$z_j = \sigma(W_z[x,h_{t-1}]_j)$

Secondly, there is a small mistake in Colah's for $h_t$. Let's ignore the different notation $h_j^{(t)}$ used in the paper and use Colah's notation $h_t$ instead. Then the equation for $h$ in Cho, et al. (2014) can be written as:

$h_t = z_t \ast h_{t - 1} + (1 - z_t) \ast \tilde{h_t}$

and if we use the same order as Colah's equation:

Paper's equation: $h_t = (1 - z_t) \ast \tilde{h_t} + z_t \ast h_{t - 1}$

Colah's equation: $h_t = (1 - z_t) \ast h_{t - 1} + z_t \ast \tilde{h_t}$

So we can actually see that for Colah's equation to match the one in the paper, we have to swap $\tilde{h_t}$ and $h_{t - 1}$ in this equation.
If you check the comments next to the GRU example on Colah's blog, you can actually see that some other people found the same mistake. Well spotted, I didn't saw it at first! :)

Comment: There are a few other differences. In colah, the expressions are all vectors, and in the original paper they are elements of those vectors, plus $\ast$ and $\odot$ are both element-wise multiplication.

Comment: How about the $h_t$?